# Sticky note app for Android

Tags: android, note-taking

I'm looking for a simple-to-run, simple-to-use sticky notes application for Android. It should have the following features:

- Ability to add, edit and delete notes.
- Ability to move notes around homescreen
- Should work with Android 7+
- Free/Paid
- Customizable

Comment: I've not tried any of the "sticky notes" apps, but while waiting for answers be welcome to browse [my list of Android note-taking apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes). [Floating Stickies](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=genius.mohammad.floating.stickies) might be an option.

Comment: Have you considered adding notes to the notification area rather than the home screen? See [StatusNote2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ipaulpro.statusnotes&hl=en_IE)